# Symfony custom query for $this->getUser() in controller

Tags: doctrine

Is it possible to use a **custom query** or maybe just **modify** the query builder used by Symfony when doing this?

```
public function profileAction(Request $request)
{
    /** @var User */
    $user = $this->getUser(); // <=== this

    return $this->getUser();
}
```

I would like to modify the query builder in order to add some left joins and get additional info from the database. Something like this:

```
public function findOneByUsernameOrEmail($username)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('u');

    return $qb
        ->addSelect('c', 'ai', 'pp')
        ->leftJoin('u.country', 'c')
        ->leftJoin('u.avatarImage', 'ai')
        ->leftJoin('u.profilePicture', 'pp')
        ->where($qb->expr()->orX(
            'u.username = :username',
            'u.email = :username'
        ))
        ->setParameter('username', $username)
        ->getQuery()
        ->getOneOrNullResult()
    ;
}
```

I would like to be able to do this **on demand**, not every time.

Comment: just add the user repository to your controller's `__construct` and access it whenever you need to. what is overriding `getUser` supposed to achieve besides providing unexpected behavior "on demand"?

Comment: My `findOneByUsernameOrEmail` was just an example, I need `getUser` in order to get the currently logged user.

Comment: You can do a workaround by doing `$user = $yourRepo()->yourCustomGetUser($this->getUser()->getUsername())` if your route is protected. If it's not and you try to access it without logging in you'll get an error `Cannot access 'getUsername()' of type string` or something like that. However, I would not recommend doing this as there is no need (imo) to fetch this data *on demand*.

Answer (score 1):

The UserProvider is responsible of fetching the User from your persistence source. The configuration is done in the security.yaml configuration file.

You can find how to use your custom query in this page of the documentation https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/user_provider.html#using-a-custom-query-to-load-the-user

Unfortunately you can't do it on demand.